# MySQL Connector with Android NDK (C++)

Tags: c++, mysql, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is there a way to get the MySQL Connector/C++ working with the Android NDK? I already installed it with the MSI installer, but I don't know exactly how to intergrate it with my Android project in Android Studio. I guess I need to add the mysqlcppconn-static.lib file  to the project somehow to be able to include all the libraries or make a connection to the installation folder somehow. Does anyone have experience with this who can help me?